# How to search for all files owned by a particular user in SAN

Tags: files, search, indexing, uid, owner

My question might be confused you but honestly that very straight forward. I have a SAN with many terabytes of data. All users have their own home directory or share directory on that (And most connections handles with NFS). I am looking for a solution to, when someone left them company, I can easily find all the files belong to him and report that to his manager in order to re-assign to somebody else. Right now I am doing that by find command like:
find / -user $USERNAME > /root/userfiles.txt
But it is so time and resource consuming.
I am thinking to a solution to index all files' metadata (like: owner) and store them into a database and when I need I just search through that list by writing a query.
So my question is, ElasticSearch or other indexing tools are the good solution for my problem at all or if not do you have any suggestion?
Note: I do not need to index the content of the files. ONLY file owner or UID

Thanks,

Comment: What OS is running on the SAN, or the system you are using to find these files?  Some versions of the 'locate' command store some security information, restrict the output based on permissions.

Comment: SAN use Nexenta. I can use any OS (Windows, Linux). But I prefer Linux (CentOS) because I can mount all SAN volumes via nfs mount.

Comment: OK, since I haven't heard from anybody I assume I should explain in another way. I am looking for a tool (preferably web app) to scan all my files in SAN and grab their metadata like (UID or file ownership). I don't need to search inside the files ONLY file name, creation data and owner. I need such this thing to find orphan file recognize how's that files belong to. I already tried: Elastic search, Apache Lucene but as I said they are text search engine! So please if anybody know a solution let me know.